# Apache Shiro: How do I add a new annotation method interceptor into the mix?

Tags: shiro

I am looking at this class: https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.1/xref/org/apache/shiro/spring/security/interceptor/AopAllianceAnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor.html

It is registering all method interceptors that work with Shiro. Among them is this interceptor:

`PermissionAnnotationMethodInterceptor` .
I want to create my own custom interceptor and integrate it into the Shiro model.
My own interceptor would be replacing the existing `PermissionAnnotationMethodInterceptor`.

How do I do it in a clean programmatic Spring Boot way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to replace the [AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor bean](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/c57fed9697d56765d5f06aee982211d881a3d9a8/support/spring-boot/spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/spring/boot/autoconfigure/ShiroAnnotationProcessorAutoConfiguration.java#L53-L55) with your own implementation

Or implement your own annotations anyway you want and disable Shiro's annotation processing: `shiro.annotations.enabled=false`